# Is it possible to render 2 queryset in ListView?

Tags: django

I am new to django and recently read a tutural that describes the usage of class based view. But when I try to render 2 different queryset (all data and filterd data) to the same template, I can't find the solution for display 2 different queryset. Can anyone suggest the best solution about this?

I know writing the function based view is much easy for this, but I hope it can be done by Class based view, thank you

```
#in view.py

from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Book

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'my_book_list'   
    queryset = Book.objects.all() 
    template_name = 'books/my_arbitrary_template_name_list.html'

# queryset = Book.objects.filter(title='war')?

#in templage.py

#Main content
<div class="main_content">
<h1>All War</h1>
<ul>
{% for book in book_list %}
<li>
    {{book.title}}
</li>
    {% for endfor %}
</ul>
</div>

#Sidebar
<div class="sidebar">
<h1>All War</h1>
<ul>
{% for book in book_list %}
<li>
    {{book.title}}
</li>
{% for endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can filter the second list in your template in the second for-loop (add an `{% if book.has_filter %}` condition where has_filter is whatever you want to test on book: Since you've already fetched all the objects from your database, there's no reason to make a second query to fetch a subset.

Comment: But in general, if you had two distinct querysets, you could do two things: add the second QuerySet to your ListView's context (overriding `def get_context_data()`) or write your own CBV on top of ListView, but I think that might become quite complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into **get_context_data** to add additional queries you want.

The view might look something like this

```
class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'my_book_list'   
    queryset = Book.objects.all() 
    template_name = 'books/my_arbitrary_template_name_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['second_queryset'] = # YOUR QUERY HERE
        return context
```

For this example the second query is *second_queryset* and it can be accessed in the html template as **{{second_queryset}}**. You can add more if you did the same for more queries.

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['second_queryset'] = # YOUR QUERY HERE
        context['third_queryset'] = # YOUR QUERY HERE
        ...
        return context
```

You can learn about it more in [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data).

Comment: The solution is what I am looking for, it works prefectly